# Responsive toggle not working in Magento2 with Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, magento2, responsive, alpine.js

I'm handling the situation with Alpine.js, but the toggle doesn't work.

It seems like Alpine is not recognised, cause the *open* variable is false from the beginning, but the class binding on the **nav** tag is not working (I simply set the hidden class if open is false, but the menu appears anyway).

I tried to add *x-data* but it seemed useless. I don't know what's happening.

I'm sure you can help me guys.

This is the *.phtml* file

```
  <!-- mobile -->
    <div x-ref="nav-mobile"
         @load.window="menu.setActiveMenu($refs['nav-mobile'])"
         class="bg-container-lighter lg:hidden z-40"
         :class="{'min-h-screen fixed bg-secondary text-white top-0 left-0 w-full' : menu.open}"
         @toggle-mobile-menu.window="menu.open = !menu.open; menu.notScrollBody();"
         @keydown.window.escape="menu.open = false"
    >
        <div class="flex items-baseline justify-between menu-icon max-h-20 px-4">
            <div class="flex justify-between w-full">
                <!-- <div x-show="menu.open">
                </div> -->
                <span width="250" height="200" x-show="menu.open"  class="text-white">
                        <?php echo $icons->renderHtml('cialdemania-mono', 'w-48 h-20', 24, 24) ?>
                </span>

                <a @click="$dispatch('toggle-mobile-menu')"
                       class="flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer"
                       :class="{ 'ml-auto': menu.open }">
                    <svg @click="$dispatch('close-static-menu')" class="hidden w-16 h-16 p-4 fill-current"
                         :class="{ 'hidden' : !menu.open, 'block': menu.open }"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"
                         viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path
                              fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M18.278 16.864a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414l-4.829-4.828-4.828 4.828a1 1 0 0
                          1-1.414-1.414l4.828-4.829-4.828-4.828a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414l4.829 4.828
                          4.828-4.828a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414l-4.828 4.829 4.828 4.828z">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                    <svg class="block w-7 h-7 fill-current"
                         :class="{ 'hidden' : menu.open, 'block': !menu.open }"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"
                         viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path
                              d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav
            class="w-full mobile-menu duration-150 ease-in-out transform border-t transition-display border-container"
            :class="{ 'hidden' : !menu.open }"
        >
            <div class="level-0">
                <span class="flex items-center transition-transform duration-150 ease-in-out transform"
                      :class="{
                        '-translate-x-full' : menu.mobilePanelActiveId,
                        'translate-x-0' : !menu.mobilePanelActiveId
                    }">
                    <button @click="$dispatch('open-brand')"
                            class="font-black flex items-center justify-between w-full px-8 py-4 border-b cursor-pointer
                        bg-container-lighter border-container hover:bg-container-darker level-0">
                       <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Brands')) ?></span>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-7 w-7 border rounded" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                             stroke="currentColor">
                          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="level-0">
                <span class="flex items-center transition-transform duration-150 ease-in-out transform"
                      :class="{
                        '-translate-x-full' : menu.mobilePanelActiveId,
                        'translate-x-0' : !menu.mobilePanelActiveId
                    }">
                     <button @click="$dispatch('open-system')"
                             class="font-black flex items-center justify-between w-full px-8 py-4 border-b
                             cursor-pointer
                        bg-container-lighter border-container hover:bg-container-darker level-0">
                       <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Systems')) ?></span>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-7 w-7 border rounded" fill="none"
                             viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        <?php foreach ($menuItems as $index => $menuItem): ?>
            <div class="level-0">
                <span
                    class="flex items-center transition-transform duration-150 ease-in-out transform"
                    :class="{
                        '-translate-x-full' : menu.mobilePanelActiveId,
                        'translate-x-0' : !menu.mobilePanelActiveId
                    }"
                >
                    <a class="flex items-center font-light w-full px-8 py-4 border-b cursor-pointer
                        bg-container-lighter border-container hover:bg-container-darker  level-0"
                       href="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($menuItem['url']) ?>"
                       title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($menuItem['name']) ?>">
                        <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($menuItem['name']) ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php if (!empty($menuItem['childData'])): ?>
                    <a class="absolute right-0 flex w-8 h-8 mr-8 border rounded cursor-pointer
                        bg-container-lighter border-container hover:bg-container hover:border-container"
                          @click="menu.mobilePanelActiveId =
                          menu.mobilePanelActiveId === '<?= /* @noEscape */ (string) $index ?>' ?
                           0 : '<?= /* @noEscape */ (string) $index ?>'"
                    >
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="24" width="24"
                             stroke="currentColor"
                             class="w-full h-full p-1"
                        >
                          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7"/>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
                <?php if (!empty($menuItem['childData'])): ?>
                    <div
                        class="absolute top-0 right-0 z-10 w-full h-full transition-transform duration-200 ease-in-out
                            translate-x-full transform bg-container-lighter"
                        :class="{
                            'translate-x-full' : menu.mobilePanelActiveId !== '<?= /* @noEscape */ (string) $index ?>',
                            'translate-x-0' : menu.mobilePanelActiveId === '<?= /* @noEscape */ (string) $index ?>',
                        }"
                    >
                        <a class="flex items-center px-8 py-4 border-b cursor-pointer bg-container border-container"
                              @click="menu.mobilePanelActiveId = 0"
                        >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="24"
                                 width="24"
                                 stroke="currentColor">
                              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                    d="M15 19l-7-7 7-7"/>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="ml-4">
                                <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($menuItem['name']) ?>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($menuItem['url']) ?>"
                           title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($menuItem['name']) ?>"
                           class="flex items-center w-full px-8 py-4 border-b cursor-pointer
                            bg-container-lighter border-container hover:bg-container-darker "
                        >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                                 viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="24"
                                 width="24"></svg>
                            <span class="ml-4"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('View All')) ?></span></a>
                        <?php foreach ($menuItem['childData'] as $subMenuItem): ?>

                            <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($subMenuItem['url']) ?>"
                               title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($subMenuItem['name']) ?>"
                               class="flex items-center w-full px-8 py-4 border-b cursor-pointer
                                bg-container-lighter border-container hover:bg-container-darker "
                            >
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                                     viewBox="0 0 24 24" height="24"
                                     width="24"></svg>
                                <span class="ml-4 text-gray-700 lg:ml-0">
                                    <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($subMenuItem['name']) ?>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

This is the *Alpine.js* script

```
 <script>
    'use strict';

    const initHeaderNavigation = () => {
        return {
            mobilePanelActiveId: null,
            hoverPanelActiveId: null,
            open: false,
            setActiveMenu(menuNode) {
                Array.from(menuNode.querySelectorAll('a')).filter(link => {
                    return link.href === window.location.href.split('?')[0];
                }).map(item => {
                    item.classList.add('underline');
                    item.closest('div.level-0') &&
                    item.closest('div.level-0').querySelector('a.level-0').classList.add('underline');
                });
            },
            notScrollBody() {

                var body = document.querySelector('body');
                body.classList.toggle('not-scroll');
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: If you don't have an `x-data`, Alpine.js will ignore this component. Since you used `menu` as a prefix, you can use `x-data="{menu: initHeaderNavigation()}"` on the main div to activate the component. However this giant piece of code has some other problems as well, it's too hard to debug at once. E.g. why do you have`$dispatch` events but no event-listeners for them?

Comment: Thanks man, sorry for late response, that `x-data="{menu: initHeaderNavigation()}"` was missing and adding it was the solution. Thanks!